# Data from YAML to javaScript through jinja2's tojson filter

Tags: javascript, python, json, yaml, jinja2

**YAML conf.yaml**

```
...
myRegEx: "^(?![_0-9])[ \\w '`,.]$"
...
```

*if I try to access myRegEx from my python it is working returning expected pattern ^(?![_0-9])[ \w '`,.]$*

**HTML index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" defer>
    const myRegEx = JSON.parse('{{conf["myRegEx"]|tojson|safe}}');
   </script>
...
```

*when I open DevTools on chrome it shows myRegEx as ^(?![_0-9])[ \\w \u0027`,.]$*

**Expected pattern should include this \w not this \\w**

*Sorry for my English, to show what I mean I put screenshot. I am not sure but it is connected with backslash parsing, how should I store myRegEx pattern in my YAML file to prevent this ?*

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: When a regular expression is in a *string* in JavaScript, the regex backslash operators require *two* backslashes, because the string constant syntax itself treats backslash characters as metacharacters. When you bury the string content *inside another string* as JSON (which is pointless, btw), you'll need *four* backslashes.

Comment: if i use 4 backslashes pattern will be different in python code